# Nativescript vue : dynamically setting image src.decode to display font icon

Tags: vue.js, fonts, components, icons, nativescript

I created a component which is supposed to display a font icon :

```
<template>
    <Image :src.decode="code" />
</template>

<script>
    const mapping = {wi_owm_200:"&#xf01e;",wi_owm_201:"&#xf01e;",wi_owm_202:"&#xf01e;"};
    
    export default {
        props: {
            icon: String,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                code: String,
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.code = 'font://' + mapping[this.icon];
        }
    };
</script>
```

In my main page I have this code calling my component :

```
<template>
    <page>
        <StackLayout>
            <myComponent icon="wi_owm_200" />
        </StackLayout>
    </page>
</template>

<script>
import myComponent from "./myComponent";

export default {
    components: {
        myComponent
    }
}
</script>
```

When I compile, instead of my pretty icon, I will get the code "&#xf01e"...
Meanwhile, directly in my main page this will work out perfectly :

```
<Image src.decode="font://&#xe900;" />
```

[Here is the playground, if you want to check it live](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=TfzsE2)

Any idea to make my component work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Button dynamically I use `:text="code"` (instead of `text.decode="& #xf164;"`), where

```
code = String.fromCharCode(0xf164);
```

Try it for Image!